# If find_if() takes too long, are there alternatives that can be used for better program performance?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, heap

I'm working on a D* Lite path planner in C++. The program maintains a priority queue of cells **(U)**, each cell have two cost values, and a key can be calculated for a cell which determine it's order on the priority queue.

```
using Cost = float;
using HeapKey = pair<Cost, Cost>;
using KeyCompare = std::greater<std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>>;
vector<pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>> U;
```

When a cell is added it is done so by using:

```
U.push_back({ k, id });
push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
```

As part of the path planning algorithm cells sometimes need to be removed, and here lies the current problem as far as I can see. I recently had help on this site to speed my program up quite a bit by using **push_heap** instead of **make_heap**, but now it seems that the part of the program that removes cells is the slowest part. Cells are removed from the priority queue by:

```
void DstarPlanner::updateVertex(unsigned int id) {
   ...
   ...
   auto it = find_if(U.begin(), U.end(), [=](auto p) { return p.second == id; });
   U.erase(it);
   ...
   ...
}
```

From my tests this seems to take roughly 80% of the time my program use for path planning. It was my hope coming here that a more time-saving method existed.

Thank you.

**EDIT - Extra information.**

```
void DstarPlanner::insertHeap(unsigned int id, HeapKey k) {
    U.push_back({ k, id });
    push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
    in_U[id]++;
  }

void DstarPlanner::updateVertex(unsigned int id) {
    Cell* u = graph.getCell(id);

    if (u->id != id_goal) {
      Cost mincost = infinity;
      for (auto s : u->neighbors) {
        mincost = min(mincost, graph.getEdgeCost(u->id, s->id) + s->g);
      }
      u->rhs = mincost;
    }
    if (in_U[id]) {
      auto it = find_if(U.begin(), U.end(), [=](auto p) { return p.second == id; });
      U.erase(it);
      in_U[id]--;
    } 
    if (u->g != u->rhs) {
      insertHeap(id, u->calculateKey());
    }
  }

vector<int> DstarPlanner::ComputeShortestPath() {

    vector<int> bestPath;
    vector<int> emptyPath;
    Cell* n = graph.getCell(id_start);    

    while (U.front().first < n->calculateKey() || n->rhs != n->g) {

      auto uid = U.front().second;
      Cell* u = graph.getCell(uid);
      auto kold = U.front().first;
      pop_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
      U.pop_back();
      in_U[u->id]--;

      if (kold < u->calculateKey()) {
        insertHeap(u->id, u->calculateKey());
      } else if (u->g > u->rhs) {
        u->g = u->rhs; 
        for (auto s : u->neighbors) {
          if (!occupied(s->id)) {
            updateVertex(s->id);
          }
        }
      } else {
        u->g = infinity;
        for (auto s : u->neighbors) {
          if (!occupied(s->id)) {
            updateVertex(s->id);
          }
        }
        updateVertex(u->id);
      }
    }

    bestPath=constructPath();
    return bestPath;
  }
```

Comment: Did you consider using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead?

Comment: `find_if` would need to do a linear search here. Then, `erase` would have to shift all the elements in the `vector` after the removed element. Both of these operations are quite time consuming. You may wish to use a different structure instead.

Comment: `in_U[id]++;` stop right there. What is `in_U`? You're complicating things. Adding code with lots of new variables that aren't declared anywhere doesn't give me any better indication of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnFilleau It's defined as:

__int in_U[SIZE*SIZE];__

SIZE is a const int I define manually. It's the size of the map (ex. if I have a 10 by 10 map I set it to 10).

Comment: @OverDemon the best place for an explanation of code is to show the code. Please read [example]. Assume all comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, sorry. It was simple because this post sort-of ended up as a bigger conversation than I was used to.

I tested my program using __is_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare())__ (KeyCompare because its a min-heap) and discovered that it quickly wasn't a heap. Solved that by using __make_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());__ but the program became even slower.

Now wondering whether to explore the __std:map__ or __std::unordered_map__ from the other suggestions, but don't have a lot of time to alter the program either. Only this week.

Comment: I liked your lazy-remove option. Then you never need to re-heapify.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Did some tests with __is_heap()__ and it seemed that my heap is disturbed after a __U.push_back({ k, id });__ and __U.erase(it);__ actions. After some testing I put __make_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());__ after those actions. However, do I need it after __U.push_back({ k, id });__? __push_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());__ comes just after it, and checking with __is_heap() it seems to correct the problem.

Comment: @JohnFilleau The heap is also not a heap according to __is_heap()__ after __pop_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());__ but __U.pop_back();__ corrects it and __is_heap()__ becomes true. So I guess my question is whether I need to use __make_heap()__ immediately after these actions, or whether its fine?

Comment: The full heap pop operation requires you to `pop_heap()` and then `pop_back()`. You shouldn't need to re-heapify after that. Read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap

Answer (score 2):

`find_if` does a linear search. It maybe faster to use:

- [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)/[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) -> Standard binary search tree implementations
- [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)/[`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) -> Standard hash table implementations

These may use a lot of memory if your elements (key-value pairs) are small integers. To avoid that you can use 3rd party alternatives like `boost::unordered_flat_map`.

Answer (score 1):

How do you re-heapify after `U.erase(it)`? Do you ever delete multiple nodes at once?

*If deletions need to be atomic between searches*, then you can

1. swap `it` with `end() - 1`,
2. erase `end() - 1`, and
3. re-heapify.

Erasing `end() - 1` is **O(1)** while erasing `it` is linear in `std::distance(it, end)`.

```
void DstarPlanner::updateVertex(unsigned int id) {
   ...
   // take the id by reference since this is synchronous
   auto it = find_if(U.begin(), U.end(), [&](const auto& p) { return p.second == id; });
   *it = std::move(*(U.end() - 1));
   U.erase((U.end() - 1));
   std::make_heap(U.begin(), U.end()); // expensive!!! 3*distance(begin, end)
   ...
}
```

*If you can delete multiple nodes between searches*, then you can use a combination of `erase` + `remove_if` to only perform one mass re-heapify. This is important be heapify is expensive.

1. `it = remove_if(begin, end, [](){ lambda }`
2. `erase(it, end)`
3. re-heapify

```
void DstarPlanner::updateVertex(const std::vector<unsigned int>& sorted_ids) {
   ...
   auto it = remove_if(U.begin(), U.end(), [&](const auto& p) { return std::binary_search(ids.begin(), ids.end(), p.second); });
   U.erase(it, U.end());
   std::make_heap(U.begin(), U.end()); // expensive!!! 3*distance(begin, end)
   ...
}
```

#### Doing better

You can possibly improve on this by replacing `std::make_heap` (which makes no assumptions about the heapiness of `[begin(), end())` with a custom method that re-heapifies a former heap around "poison points" -- it only needs to initially inspect the elements around the elements that were swapped. This sounds like a pain to write and I'd only do it if the resulting program was still too slow.

#### Have you thought of...

Just not even removing elements from the heap? The fact you're using a heap tells me that the algorithm designers suggested a heap. If they suggested a heap, then they likely didn't envision random removals. This is speculation on my part. I'm otherwise not familiar with D* lite.

Comment: Re-heapify, that's not something I've considered I have to admit. Not a novice in C++ I'd say, but neither an expert, and this part with the heap etc. is something I've not created myself, but adapted from some code I found. 

I've made an edit to my post and added what I think is the important parts, the functions that deal with finding the path and manipulating the heap/priority queue, while leaving out the parts that print the path and such.

I do delete multiple cells per planning.

Also taking a look at your suggestions. Thank you ^^

Comment: If you have a heap, and then you turn that heap into not a heap, then any functions that expect your heap to be a heap will have undefined behavior. It may be valid to _not_ re-heapify -- but that entirely depends on what you do with the elements after you remove elements from the container.

Comment: @OverDemon looking at your edits, I have no idea what I'm supposed to get out of those.

Comment: The algorithm and the heap structure have nothing to do with C++ here. All heaps operate the same and have the same basic operations. You use them when you want a priority queue.

Comment: Sorry, I had hoped it might give a better overview but seems I was mistaken. Wanted to show how the planning part of the program works.

The function computeShortestPath selects the cell with the 'cheapest' key value and from there it might call updateVertex in certain cells. In updateVertex is where cells are removed, and where the problem is, in the second if-sentence.

Wanted to show that I, currently, do not re-heapify, I believe.

Comment: Anytime you call `pop_heap` or `push_heap`, the range `[begin, end)` is required to be a valid heap (has the heap invariant). Otherwise you're invoking undefined behavior. You can use `std::is_heap` as a debugging tool to see if there are any points in your program where `U` is not a valid `heap` before a call to `pop_heap` or `push_heap`.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Will look into that and read up on heaps in C++. As for your suggestion about not removing elements from the heap, will look into that also, but it's part of the algorithm... Though I do think I remember an example program in D* Lite that used the concept of a 'lazy remove'. Will re-examine that also.

Comment: If you can get away with a lazy remove, then you never have to re-heapify. `push_heap` and `pop_heap` will take advantage of the fact that the only nodes being modified are the root and the last, which removes the constant churn of `3 * O(N)` re-heapfiy operations to `O(log N)` and `O(2 x log N)` respectively.

Comment: "read up on heaps in C++" just read up on heaps. C++ be dammed (except for the `cppreference` pages on `push_heap` and `pop_heap`.) I just learned about heaps on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE5I0xACpZs